# MySQL Select top two people with most submitted videos, where type=1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of videos submitted by people:

```
+----+-----------+------+---------+
| id | by_person | type | title   |
+----+-----------+------+---------+
|  1 |         3 |    1 | title1  |
|  2 |         4 |    1 | title2  |
|  3 |         3 |    1 | title3  |
|  4 |         4 |    2 | title4  |
|  5 |         3 |    1 | title5  |
|  6 |         6 |    2 | title6  |
|  7 |         6 |    2 | title7  |
|  8 |         4 |    2 | title8  |
|  9 |         3 |    1 | title9  |
| 10 |         4 |    1 | title10 |
| 11 |         4 |    1 | title11 |
| 12 |         3 |    1 | title12 |
+----+-----------+------+---------+
```

How do I `SELECT` the top two people who have submitted the most videos with type=1 so I get a presentation like this?

```
1. Person(3) - 5 videos
2. Person(4) - 3 videos
```

Comment: You should show your own efforts, What have you tried so far. Is there any query you wrote or tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT by_person, count(*) AS total
FROM videos
WHERE type = 1
GROUP BY by_person
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 2
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2916/22

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
select by_person, sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NumType1
from videos v
group by by_person
order by NumType1 desc
limit 2
```

Comment: Is using a `case` statement any faster than using `WHEE type=1`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat . . . Actually, using `where type = 1` could be faster, if you have an index on `type`.  Otherwise, the difference between the two would be negligible.  I prefer the `case` statement because it makes it clearer (to me) what is being added up.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT by_person, COUNT(title)
FROM videos
WHERE type = 1
GROUP BY by_person
ORDER BY COUNT(title) DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: `COUNT(title)` will always give you 1 because you don't group it.

Comment: @S.Visser As `COUNT` is an aggregate function, I shouldn't group by title. But the query was incorrect anyway, as I grouped by `id` and not `by_person`, but it is fixed now.